# PointCloud To LaserScan

Tags: ros, ros-kinetic, vrep, laserscan, pointcloud

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello.
I'm new to ros.I set my scene in VREP and got my robot using kinect.
I'm trying to create a map of the environment, but for this I need to convert the data from pointcloud to laserscan, but I have no idea how to do this.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/288924/pointcloud-to-laserscan/) by [Dieisson Martinelli](https://answers.ros.org/users/34690/dieisson-martinelli/) on ROS Answers with karma: 11 on 2018-04-17

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Please see:

- #q224463
- <strike>#q11232</strike>
- <strike>#q238481</strike>
- <strike>#q235009</strike>
- #q10568
- #q188444
- #q73186

This has been asked many times before, but it can be a little difficult to find these answers using the search function on the site. You can try entering the following search terms in Google:

```
<question> site:answers.ros.org
```

where `<question>` is your question. This will perform a search of ROS Answers using your question as a term.

For example, your question would be:

https://www.google.com/search?q=convert+point+cloud+to+laserscan+site%3Aanswers.ros.org

---

Originally posted by [jayess](https://answers.ros.org/users/26450/jayess/) with karma: 6155 on 2018-04-17

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [paulbovbel](https://answers.ros.org/users/3632/paulbovbel/) on 2018-07-06**:
Funnily enough, the links provided mostly talk about how to convert a laserscan into a pointcloud :)

**Comment by [jayess](https://answers.ros.org/users/26450/jayess/) on 2018-07-06**:
Good catch. This is what happens when you have too many tabs open at once.

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

There is a package to convert pointclouds to laserscans - http://wiki.ros.org/pointcloud_to_laserscan. The parameters are documented on the wiki, and some sample launch files are provided in the package source.

---

Originally posted by [paulbovbel](https://answers.ros.org/users/3632/paulbovbel/) with karma: 4518 on 2018-07-06

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

This [question](https://answers.ros.org/question/254302/how-to-use-pointcloud_to_laserscan/) tackles the same problem (but with velodyne pointcloud) using the [pointcloud_to_laserscan](http://wiki.ros.org/pointcloud_to_laserscan) package.
Here is another [example](http://www.theconstructsim.com/ros-qa-120-how-to-convert-a-pointcloud-into-a-laser-scan/) of converting pointcloud to laserscan that you can checkout.

---

Originally posted by [pavel92](https://answers.ros.org/users/32610/pavel92/) with karma: 1655 on 2018-07-06

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1